# Are flu shots universal or regional?

Tags: health, vaccinations

Though I (cough, cough) have good health at home, when I travel I tend to pick up bugs. This repeatedly ruins a few days on holidays, with long-distance plane travel a major culprit.

A simple prevention is to take a flu (regular flu—this is not about COVID) shot. But the flu strains that are dominant in my region may not necessarily be the ones spreading elsewhere in the world, and it is those that distress my immune system the most. (I gathered that I fall ill when away from home because my system is not sufficiently accustomed to combatting the local flu variants elsewhere.)

Are flu shots universal or region-specific?

Comment: In UK they are a best guess about the strains that will be likely to be around during the next 'flu season'. Related: [A Universal Influenza Vaccine: How Close Are We?](https://asm.org/Articles/2019/August/A-Universal-Influenza-Vaccine-How-Close-Are-We)

Comment: You didn't ask, but I stopped "picking up bugs" after flights when I started wiping down my seat (tray, screen, arms, seatbelt etc etc) with a sanitizing wipe the moment I sit down. It's not perfect (I caught Covid on a plane even with a KN95, 4 Covid vaccines, and this habit) but it has reduced the colds/flu/ugh that I used to get after almost every flight to nearly zero.

Comment: @KateGregory That's valuable advice. Thanks. What's the best way to do this? A <100m container of alcohol + kitchen towels? I doubt they'd let me board with any alcohol at all. With "baby wipes" in their own container? That's a bit bulky. With Lysol wipes? Same. That just leaves individually wrapped wipes. Is that right?

Comment: @KateGregory Intriguing also because I was certain that the air circulating among hundreds of strangers is what spreads the germs (and even the cleanest airlines have little remedy for it beyond UV rays). I expected that exposure is inevitable. This is a nice alternative theory.

Comment: You can get little "travel packs" of 10 or 20 wipes. They are about twice the size of a deck of cards. I keep them in the side mesh pocket of my backpack, easy to grab. Also, Covid is airborne, but colds (And I think flu?) are fomites, which is to say particles on surfaces. Airlines do run hella good hepa filters, they do have some remedy for airborne, but it might not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A simple prevention is to take a flu (regular flu—this is not about COVID) shot. But the flu strains that are dominant in my region may not necessarily be the ones spreading elsewhere in the world, and it is those that distress my immune system the most. (I gathered that I fall ill when away from home because my system is not sufficiently accustomed to combatting the local flu variants elsewhere.)

My understanding is that flu "strains" (the classifications used for flu vaccines do not necessarily correspond the scientific use of a strain) within a season are generally global, although there are regional differences in the relative frequencies. Flu vaccines are generally the less effective types since the viruses evolve fast and the vaccines used en masse can only be made according to predictions that may be spot on or completely off or partially right.

But the details is beyond my knowledge and more for the [Medical Sciences SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/).

> Are flu shots universal or region-specific?

But this is relatively simple to answer. Most if not all manufacturers produce most flu vaccines, most with three or four types of viruses, according to the predictions and recommendations made by the experts at the WHO, which may match better or worse with the prevalent strains each winter.

The WHO makes two recommendations each year for each winter/flu season (respectively in the [northern](https://www.who.int/publications/m/item/recommended-composition-of-influenza-virus-vaccines-for-use-in-the-2022-2023-northern-hemisphere-influenza-season) and [southern hemisphere](https://www.who.int/news/item/23-09-2022-new-recommendations-for-the-composition-of-influenza-vaccines-in-2023-for-the-southern-hemisphere)). The predictions are partly based on the premise that the strains prevalent in the previous northern/southern hemisphere season would be prevalent in the coming southern/northern season.

In each flu season, the composition is relatively uniform for the same type of vaccines (depending the number of virus types included and the vaccine technology used).

---

If you are travelling in the same hemisphere, there is unlikely much for you to do vaccination-wise with regards to flu. If you are travelling to another hemisphere, it depends on the timing of your trip and personal conditions. Flu in general is a lot less prevalent in summer. Vaccines also take time to take effect (so for short trips it is unlikely to be useful to get vaccine at the destination).

There are also many reasons for sickness after travelling due to various reasons, most of the times, it is not the flu. Of course, there are a lot of other bugs, but usual hygiene measures like handwashing and now maskwearing should be sufficient precautions for most people. Each person is different of course and you should consult a travel clinic to get more information, but in general I don't think flu vaccination differences really matter here.

Comment: I'd of course note that you should be wearing a KF94 mask or better to protect yourself. Wearing a regular medical mask when no one else is wearing one doesn't actually protect you.